# HTTPClient/doc/GetAuthInfo (wrong name: GetAuthInfo)

Tags: java, eclipse

It's a simple java program. iT works perfectly on command prompt but while using eclipse it gives me the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HTTPClient/doc/GetAuthInfo (wrong name: GetAuthInfo)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

The program I m trying is:

```
public class GoodFirstProgram
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        System.out.println( "Hello Again" );
        System.out.println( "I like typing this." );
        System.out.println( "This is fun." );
        System.out.println( "Yay! Printing." );
        System.out.println( "I'd much rather you 'not'." );
        System.out.println( "I \"said\" do not touch this." );
    }
}
```

Please help. I don't understand why I would require HTTPClient.

Comment: you can serch an answer here: <http://javarevisited.blogspot.it/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the class>>Run as>>Run Configuration..
and then from project select your respective project
and then select the appropriate main class as  GoodFirstProgram in your case,and give a try whether it works